# Making secure HttpRequests via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httprequest

Considering the fact that browsers extensions' source code is open source, is there a secure way to call an API from the extension itself (meaning not storing API  credentials in code)?

I want to get some sensitive data from an external API on demand.

I'm pretty much clueless on how to approach this.

Comment: There's no way. Do it on your server and communicate with the extension via a temporary token.